# How to check for any damage done after sudden power unplug?

Tags: windows, power

So I recently moved in together with my girlfriend. 
And just a moment ago while I was playing a game (Civ 5) she accidently unplugged the power cable to my PC.

I swtiched on the power again, and turned my PC back on and started Windows normally.

After that I restarted, shut it down normally. Turned it back on and now I'm here.

Wondering if it's possible to get like a damage control report? Or to see if anything has been damaged? So far my PC seems to work just fine.

However I did get an error about the Windows Performance being slow. I choose to keep the current color scheme and let Windows inform me if the performance decreased again. I've gotten this error once or twice in the past. It's not really a problem. But I wonder could it indicate that damage was done?

Comment: What is the error?  There is no single way to detect a problem after a computer loses power, there are a dozen things that could happen, and their solutions are all different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While anything is possible, the *most common* damage that occurs from an unexpected power loss to a computer is data corruption. Checking for hardware damage can be difficult and it may not be conclusive (intermittent) or even show up for some time. But usually, if there’s no immediate problems, then you can assume that it’s okay physically, especially if the sudden shut down was merely due to a power loss as opposed to a power *spike*. You should however make sure that your files are okay. You can replace hardware and reinstall Windows, but the files you create are irreplaceable, so if there is corruption, the faster you detect it, the better the chances of recovery (especially if you keep backups).

## Technical

When a complex OS like Windows is running, there are all kinds of open files. To increase performance, the OS does not always write everything to the disk the moment the write command is issued and buffers them so that they can be written in batches. This makes the system more responsive by cutting down on disk accesses.

Because of the fact that files are left open and writes are buffered, if the system loses power unexpectedly, there may have been data that was still in memory and not yet written to the disk, and therefore you could lose some data. For example, you may have had a file open in an editor, and even if you *did* clicks save, it may not have been written to the disk yet and been in cache, so when you power back up, you find that the changes are gone (or the whole file is empty/corrupt if you had never saved yet).

Worse, because of how file-systems work and how OSes manage files, sometimes things can get corrupted. The OS may have been in the middle of a file-system operation like moving a file, deleting a file, or updating the file-system when the power went out. In this case, the file-system can be in an indeterminate state and files could have been messed up and making new changes to the disk (like simply booting up), could end up corrupting files or causing them to be lost altogether.

## Auto-Repair

Your best bet to check for damage after an unexpected power loss is to scan the file-system for corruption. What *normally* happens is that Windows writes a flag to the disk to let it know that the file-system is active, and clears the flag when it is not (e.g., when it shuts down). If the power suddenly goes out, the next time that Windows boots, it detects that the flag is set and thus the file-system may be corrupt. In that case, it automatically runs a scan of the disk during its pre-boot phase (before Windows actually loads, and therefore no other file activity takes place that could corrupt the disk).

Unfortunately, Windows’ automatic scan does not always trigger, so whenever you have an unexpected shut down like that, it’s always a good idea to boot up in safe-mode first (so that no programs or anything run and make changes to the disk), and run a scan yourself.

## Advice

You can scan your disk by right-clicking the drive in *My Computer*, selecting *Properties*, then clicking the *Check Now* button in the *Tools* tab. You can also open a command-prompt (*Run* ⇨ `cmd`) and run the `chkdsk` command to see the technical details of the scan.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it should be absolutely fine! You could do a SMART health check on your hard drive(s), however.

It's not really necessary, but here's a link to a guide anyway: http://techmell.net/how-to/hard-drive-health-dying-checking-errors/

Good luck!

Comment: Good point. That’s one of the few ways to check for hardware damage (especially for spinning drives which really don’t like being started or stopped). Of course most drives made in the past 20 or so years should be able to auto-park the heads even with sudden power loss, but it’s best/safest to “trust but verify”.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing to have been "broken" by the power cut would be data related to the programs you are using at the time, meaning files they may have been writing to at the time.  (Of course, the OS is one of those programs.)

Aside from a general hard drive scan (which is a good idea), you could focus on the game you were playing.  If Civ 5 writes to any files on the fly (autosave?), then in addition to scanning the game folder in particular, you could just try loading the last saved game (especially autosaved game), and loading the game itself and the saved gamed will depend on and therefore test a lot of the files the system might have been writing to at the time of the power cut.

If **loading your last saved game** is not a problem (and you recognize the last saved game listed as really the last one that should have been saved), that's a good sign.

Comment: `If loading your last saved game is not a problem (and you recognize the last saved game listed as really the last one that should have been saved), that's a good sign.`   Assuming that the save was recent enough to be one of the last disk writes, then yes, you can *probably* relax (and maybe consider a UPS). (Also, don’t forget that there could be other files open in the background.)